# Why won't a longer token in an alternation be matched?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, alternation, regex-alternation

I am using ruby 2.1, but the same thing can be replicated on rubular site.

If this is my string:

```
儘管中國婦幼衛生監測辦公室制定的
```

And I do a regex match with this expression:

```
(中國婦幼衛生監測辦公室制定|管中)
```

I am expecting to get the longer token as a match.

```
中國婦幼衛生監測辦公室制定
```

Instead I get the second alternation as a match.

As far as I know it does work like that when not in chinese characters.

If this is my string:

```
foobar
```

And I use this regex:

```
(foobar|foo)
```

Returned matching result is `foobar`. If the order is in the other way, than the matching string is `foo`. That makes sense to me.

Comment: What makes you think longer matches returns first?

Comment: Just guessing. But seems like regex engines are eager and return whatever they find first. Is there a way to make it return "best" (meaning longest) match.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your assumption that regex matches a longer alternation is incorrect.

### *If you have a bit of time, let's look at how your regex works...*

<sub>Quick refresher: How regex works: The state machine always reads from left to right, backtracking where necessary.</sub>

There are two pointers, one on the Pattern:

```
(cdefghijkl|bcd)
```

The other on your String:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
```

The pointer on the String moves from the left. As soon as it can return, it **will**:

[image: x]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/ac652df1ed094be6c5d66c14a2728ac1.png))</sub>

Let's turn that into a more "sequential" sequence for understanding:

[image: y]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/386aecb351fc2eb34f9c5db269a66dab.png))</sub>

Your `foobar` example is a different topic. As I mentioned [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179366/priority-in-regex-manipulating/25180429#25180429):

> How regex works: The state machine always reads from left to right. `,|,, == ,`, as it always will only be matched to the first alternation.

**That's good, Unihedron, but how do I force it to the first alternation?**

Look!<sup>`*`</sup>

```
^(?:.*?\Kcdefghijkl|.*?\Kbcd)
```

Here have a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rF9pC6/1).

This regex first attempts to match the entire string with the first alternation. Only if it fails **completely** will it then attempt to match the second alternation. `\K` is used here to **keep** the match with the contents *behind* the construct `\K`.

---

<sub>`*`: `\K` was supported in Ruby since 2.0.0.</sub>

**Read more:**

- [The Stack Overflow Regex Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)
- [On greedy vs non-greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075130/what-is-the-difference-between-and-regular-expressions/3075532#3075532)

Ah, I was bored, so I optimized the regex:

```
^(?:(?:(?!cdefghijkl)c?[^c]*)++\Kcdefghijkl|(?:(?!bcd)b?[^b]*)++\Kbcd)
```

You can see a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/nH2vI9/1).

Comment: Great write-up..includes the simple answer to OP's problem (`How regex works: The state machine always reads from left to right, backtracking where necessary.`) as well as an optimized expression.