# Regex How to make groups greedy

Tags: regex

I want to build a tokenizer that allows me to pass in patterns.

As i understand in a normal OR group the first match wins.

This pattern:

```
(?<integer>[0-9]+)|(?<float>[0-9]+[.][0-9]+)|(?<invalid>[^\s]+)
```

Would never match the `float` group since the `integer` group would always be matched first.
The behaviour i want is that the first two groups match as greedy as they can and the last group matches as ungreedy as it can.

`2.2BLA3.1` should be matched as `float(2.2), invalid(BLA), float(3.1)`

my usecase does not allow me to give the tokens a fixed ordering, so i have to solve this by adding additional control characters to the regex expresion.

What needs to be added?

---

EDIT:

There have been great suggestions so far, thanks in advance.
One suggestion is to change the Ordering. Unfortunatelly my usecase does not allow me to give the tokens a fixed ordering. So i can not predict the order in which i am given the group information.

Another very interesting one is to make the `integer` group more restrictive. This will also not fit the usecase. I did not mention this before but essentally i get a list of tuples `tokenname` and `tokenpattern` and i have to fit them into one big pattern.

```
(?<integer>[0-9]+)|(?<float>[0-9]+[.][0-9]+)|(?<invalid>[^\s]+)
```

This pattern can be the result of reworking a list like

```
{
    {"integer","[0-9]+"},
    {"float","[0-9]+[.][0-9]+"}
}
```

When i asked what needs to be added i was hoping to use some control sequence to change the behaviour of the groups themselves.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why won't a longer token in an alternation be matched?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25511528/3622940)

Answer (score 2):

```
(?<integer>(?:[0-9](?!\d*\.))+)|(?<float>[0-9]+[.][0-9]+)|(?<invalid>[^\s]+)
```

You can try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/bZ8aY1/2

Answer (score 1):

If you append `(?![.])` to the definition of integer (that is a zero-width lookahead that matches only if there is no dot after the current position), it should work. Otherwise, you could try to switch `<float>` and `<integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

An integer looks the same as a float but has a more strict regex, so it should be safe to look for a float before an integer. This way, if it can match a float at all then it will, if it can't then it'll look for just a regular integer instead:

```
(?<float>[0-9]+[.][0-9]+)|(?<integer>[0-9]+)|(?<invalid>[^\s]+)
```

Then to make the last group (invalid) as non-greedy as possible, you can use the `+?` modifier (although it's worth noting that this will match one character at a time into the `invalid` matches result):

```
(?<float>[0-9]+[.][0-9]+)|(?<integer>[0-9]+)|(?<invalid>[^\s]+?)
```

It's also worth mentioning that `.75` is technically a valid floating point value - you may want to update it so that the integer part of the floating point value is optional:

```
(?<float>[0-9]*[.][0-9]+)|(?<integer>[0-9]+)|(?<invalid>[^\s]+?)
```

Comment: Yes, but my usecase does not allow me to give the tokens a fixed ordering. So i have no control wheather or not `integer` ends up before `float` or not.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. It doesn't matter what order they appear in the data being matched against, just by trying to match a float before an integer you solve the problem. All floats start with an integer value, but not all integers start with a floating point value

Comment: The parts are passed into the function that creates the combination. All i could do is sort them by length but that is guessing.