# specifying regular expression preference (order of precedence important)

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex which is trying to parse price out of a string:

```
  $pattern = '#([Ii][Dd][Rr].?\s*[0-9.,]+)|
                ([Rr][Pp].?\s*[0-9.,]+)|
                ([Pp][Rr][Ii][Cc][Ee]:?\s*[0-9.,]+)|
                (\s[0-9]+\s?[Kk]\s)|
                ([0-9]+[Rr][Bb])|
                ([0-9.,]+\s*[Rr][Ii][Bb][Uu])|
                (\b[0-9]+[.,][0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]+)#u';
 $matches = array();
 preg_match($pattern, $caption, $matches);
```

When tested with the following string:

```
"ABBY TOP
 Colour : POLKA BLACK
 Weight : 0,18
 Price : 185,000
 Material : Kaos Semi-Fleece
 Size : Panjang / Length: 55 cm (depan), 72 (belakang)"
```

This always parses the `0.18` as the price, while I wanted the `Price: 185,000` to be the real price.
Is there anything wrong in my regex?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match? The last optional match (`(\b[0-9]+[.,][0-9]+[.,]?[0-9]+)`) is going to match any number, even if it hits it before it gets to the word "price" or some other match. Do you really need that group?

Comment: Don't use regex for this. Just split the string on newlines and then again on `:` to produce key-value pairs.

Comment: I think I want to make it tighter such that it matches 3 digit (thousands) or 3 digit (millions), so 2.00 should be invalid, but 2.000 is valid .. I tried enforcing this by changing it to  (\b[0-9]+[.,][0-9]{3}[.,]?[0-9]{3})#u'; but this doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No offense, but... Before I give you the answer, let me point to you the many fixes to apply in your regex.

While you're attempting a dual case match, `[Ii][Dd][Rr]` isn't a good idea: use `idr` as usual, but include the [case-`i`nsensitive flag: `#i`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12411066/3622940)

[Using `\d` over `[0-9]` makes the world happier.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16622773/3622940)

Also, your Price entry is `Price : 185,000` but the subpattern `([Pp][Rr][Ii][Cc][Ee]:?\s*[0-9.,]+)` won't capture it because of the space before the colon. Add `\s*`.

See also:

- [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)
- [Regular-Expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info)
- [RexEgg](http://www.rexegg.com/)

Now back to placing precedence into account. You can use the same technique from [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25511635/3622940), which makes your regex:

```regex
/^.*?\Kidr.?\s*[\d.,]+|
.*?\Krp.?\s*[\d.,]+|
.*?\Kprice:?\s*[\d.,]+|
.*?\K\s\d+\s?k\s|
.*?\K\d+rb|
.*?\K[0-9.,]+\s*ribu|
.*?\K\b\d+[.,]\d+[.,]?\d+/xis
Regex101 Demo
```